# Proving tangency

Tags: geometry

> $PA$ is tangent to $\odot O$ at $A$, and $PBC$ cuts $\odot O$. $S$ is the foot of $A$ onto $PO$. Let $\odot(ACS)$ intersect $BC$ at $T$. Show that $\dfrac{BT}{BC}=\dfrac{AT^2}{AC^2}$.[image]

I suppose that we only need to show **$AB$ is tangent to $\odot(ATC)$ at $A$**. If so, we get $\angle BAT=\angle BCA$, then $\triangle BAT\sim\triangle BCA$. Therefore $\dfrac{AT}{AC}=\dfrac{BT}{BA}$, which implies $\dfrac{AT^2}{AC^2}=\dfrac{BT^2}{BA^2}$. Notice from power of a point theorem, $BA^2=BT\times BC$. This gives $\dfrac{BT}{BC}=\dfrac{AT^2}{AC^2}$ finally.

I also noticed that $\angle ASO=\angle PAO=90^\circ$, so by projection theorem and power of a point theorem,$$PS\times PO=PA^2=PB\times PC.$$Thus $B,S,O,C$ concyclic.

Back to proving tangency, it's equivalent to $\angle BAS=\angle SCA$. Now this gets independent from point $T$, which was the last to be constructed.

Comment: How is the point S chosen?

Comment: looks like S is constructed such that AS is perpendicular to PO based on your partial solution.

Comment: @cr001 that's right. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Extend $PO$ to intersect the circumcircle of $\triangle ATC$, centered at $Q$, where the intersection point is $M$. Since $\angle ASM = 90^\circ$, we know $AM$ pass through $Q$.

By $B,S,O,C$ cocyclic, $\angle OBC=\angle OSC = \angle MSC = \angle MAC = \angle QAC$. Therefore isosceles triangles $\triangle QAC$ and $\triangle OBC$ are similar and $\angle QCA = \angle OCB$, implying $\angle QCO=\angle ACB$. Since $QO$ is the symmetric line of circle $Q$, $\angle QAO=\angle QCO=\angle ACB$.

$$\angle QAO=\angle ACB\space\space (1)$$

[image]

On the other hand, $\angle AQT = 2\angle ACB = \angle AOB$, which means isosceles triangles $\triangle AQT$ and $\triangle AOB$ are similar. This means $\angle QAT = \angle OAB$ which means $\angle QAO=\angle TAB$.

$$\angle QAO=\angle TAB \space \space (2)$$

Combining (1) and (2) we have $\angle TAB = \angle ACB$ giving your desired tangency.